# Trouble updating OpenGL 2.1 to > 3 on AMD/ATI FireGL V3300

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, steam, opengl

I am trying since last many days to update OpenGL from 2.1 to greater than 3.0 as it is requested by Steam while trying to run DOTA 2 on my computer. I have a HP workstation xw4400 with ATI Fire V3300 card running Ubuntu 14.04.3 linux kernel 13.9. I am using DVI output cable for connection to monitor.

I have tried installing oibaf drivers but the OpenGL version remains same when I checked it with "glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version". What i am missing or is my hardware is old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to bring the bad news, but as far as I can tell, that card [only supports OpenGL 2.0](http://gpureview.com/firegl-v3300-card-464.html).
With only 128Mb of RAM, the card would probably not be able to handle DOTA2 anyway...

Comment: Got it. However on the bright side I learned valuable lessons in Linux/Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, in my opinion that's the linux way. You just keep learning. =-) Also, please accept the answer if you felt it was right. Thanks.